# PrimeFaces TabView how to set tab width in CSS

Tags: html, css, jsf, primefaces, tabview

I would like to change default 25% of 'tab view`, but now it is not showing.

This is the css content:

```
.ui-tabs.ui-tabs-left > .ui-tabs-nav {
   width: 10%;
}

.ui-tabs.ui-tabs-left > .ui-tabs-panels {
   width: 90%;
}
```

Html:

```
<p:tabView orientation="left" effect="fade" effectDuration="slow" dynamic="true">
      <p:tab title="xxx">
          <ui:include src="/request.xhtml"/> 
      </p:tab>
      <p:tab title="yyy">
      </p:tab>
      <p:tab title="zzz">
      </p:tab>
```

Comment: Effectively your question is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8768317/how-do-i-override-default-primefaces-css-with-custom-styles. The specificity part (I just tried online in the PF showcase with a browser developer tool and specificity is what is key here)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I override default PrimeFaces CSS with custom styles?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8768317/how-do-i-override-default-primefaces-css-with-custom-styles)

Comment: This solve the issue.